# Google Chrome won't load localhost sites while offline

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I develop a few websites locally on my laptop. I noticed recently, that Chrome refused to load my sites running on Apache (with Ubuntu 10.04) when I'm not connected to the internet. From what I've managed to find while searching the issue is that Chrome simply won't load any web sites without an active internet connection. I can't seem to find any info on how to override this behavior and was hoping someone could help me out with this.

Comment: +1, yeppp It sucks a lot with chrome-browser - no support of offline mode in chrome, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Chrome are you using? Maybe this issue thread will help? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55041

Comment: I'm on 6.0.472.63, but it certainly looks like that issue ticket will solve my problem once it's pushed to the stable build. I used to run the dailies, but got tired of random stability regressions. It's a small enough issue that I can just wait, especially since I know it's coming. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab, but in 'Options' -> 'Under the Hood' -> 'Change Proxy Settings' there is an 'Ignored Hosts' tab. Click on this and ensure that the following entries exist:

- localhost
- 127.0.0.0/8
- *.local

Hope this helps.